# Prove that $\int_Xf(x+y)dm(x) = \int_{X+y}f(x)dm(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

The following problem is from my exercise sheet. I was able to write a solution, but I am unsure in some passages, mainly in the sup equations in the second part, and I would be very grateful if someone could verify my solution. Any comments and suggestions will be the most appreciated, likewise critics concerning the clarity and writing style.

Prove that, if $X \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $m(X) < \infty, \ y\in \mathbb{R}^N \text{ and } f:y+X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathcal{M}(y+X)$-measurable function, then the map $g:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x+y)$ is measurable and 
$$
\int_Xf(x+y)dm(x) = \int_{X+y}f(x)dm(x)
$$
where $y+X \doteq \{y+x ; \  x \in X \}$, $\mathcal{M}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and m is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

My solution is as follows:

Since f is $\mathcal{M}(y+X)$-measurable, then, given any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\{ x+y \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ f(x+y) < \alpha \} \in \mathcal{M}(y+X) = \{ (y+X) \cap A; \ A \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)  \} 
$$
$$
\therefore \{ x+y \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ f(x+y) < \alpha \} \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)
$$
$$
\therefore \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ f(x+y) < \alpha\} = -y + \{ x+y \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ f(x+y) < \alpha \} \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N),
$$
since translated Lebegue measurable sets remain measurable. But then 
$$
\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ f(x+y) < \alpha\} \in \{X\cap A;\  A \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})^N \} = \mathcal{M}(X) 
$$
$$
\therefore \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ f(x+y) < \alpha\} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N; \ g(x) < \alpha\} \in \mathcal{M}(X)
$$
Since $\alpha$ in any real number, we have that g is $\mathcal{M}(X)$-measurable.

Now, since $g$ is measurable and limited, there exists the number$\int_X g(x)dm(x)$ and, by definition of the integral:
\begin{equation*}
\int_Xf(x+y)dm(x) 
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& = \int_X g(x)d\text{m}(x) \\
& = \sup\left\{\int_X \phi(x)dm(x); \phi \text{ is simple }, \phi(x) \leq g(x) \forall x \in X  \right\} \\
& = \sup\left\{\int_X \Phi(x+y)dm(x); \Phi \text{ is simple }, \Phi(x+y) \leq f(x+y) \forall x \in X \right\} \\
& = \sup \left\{\int_{y+X} \psi(t)dm(t); \psi \text{ is simple }, \psi(t)\leq f(t) \forall t \in y+X \right\} \\
& = \int_{y+X}f(x) dm(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: What does the notation $X\in\mathcal{M}({\bf R}^N)$ mean?

Comment: @Jack this means that X is Lebesgue measurable. I am using $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra.